# How to map SAX (Symbolic Aggregrate Approximation) back to time series

Tags: java, r, bigdata

I converted my long time series into Piecewise Polynomial Approximation and then into symbolic form using SAX representation. Basically, I am using these algorithm to detect motifs (repeating patterns in data). After identifying repeated patterns in the symbols, how do I map these symbols back to the time series so that I can isolate motifs within the time series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authors of the paper, "Visualizing Variable-Length Time Series Motifs" solved this problem by storing the starting position of each SAX word and its corresponding length.